# Simplify $\mathcal{O}(x\log x)-\frac{(x\log x)}{2}$ as $x\to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, number-theory, asymptotics

Let $\mathcal{O}$ denote the Big O notation. My question is:

> 1. Simplify $\mathcal{O}(x\log x)-\frac{(x\log x)}{2}$ as $x\to \infty$

> 2. If we have $ \frac{1}{2}(x\log x)\leq L\leq \mathcal{O}(x\log x)$ so can we say that $L=\mathcal{O}(x\log x)$?

I tried writing: as $x\to \infty$    $\mathcal{O}(x\log x)-\frac{(x\log x)}{2}=   \mathcal{O}(x\log x)- \mathcal{O}(x\log x) $

Can we write the above equation?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is just $O(x\log x)$.

Comment: @Gary But where is the mistake in my attempt?

Comment: Hello :) Instead of $f\in\mathcal{O}(x\log x) $ we often write $f=\mathcal{O}(x\log x) $. Let $f\in\mathcal{O}(x\log x) $, then there exist $C, D>0$ such that $|f(x)|\leq Cx\log x$ for all $x\geq D$. Hence, $|f(x) -1/2x\log x|\leq (C+1/2) x\log x|$ for $x\geq D$.

Comment: @Jochen Thanks. So if we have $ \frac{1}{2}(x\log x)\leq L\leq \mathcal{O}(x\log x)$ so can we say that $L=\mathcal{O}(x\log x)$?

Comment: @Gary I have edited my question. Please have a look